# Can thunderbird wrap quoted messages automatically in plain text mode?

Tags: email, thunderbird, reply, word-wrap

My setting for replying in Thunderbird is 'plain text', which I find handiest for replying between the quoted lines starting with '>' (and replies to replies with '>>' and so on).

When I reply to an originally-HTML message with a long line, it only gets a '>' once. If I want it displayed with '>' at the start I need to do the wrapping myself.

So if I get the message

```
I am sending you this really long line, so if you want to have any word wrapping done you'll have to do it yourself!
```

then in my reply it will look like this

```
 > I am sending you this really long line, so if you want to have any word wrapping done you'll have to do it yourself!
```

but can Thunderbird be set to do something like

```
> I am sending you this really long line, so if you want to 
> have any word wrapping done you'll have to do it yourself!
```

automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in OSX and Linux Thunderbird v.60.  It's on the Ctrl-R key, or Rewrap on the Edit menu when composing a message.  (You have to select the section you want to re-wrap, and it works best when you select at least one empty line [containing only a '> '] at the end of a section.)

When it works right, it's great; but sometimes it gets confused and you end up rewrapping by hand.